# ассоциативные неупорядоченные и упорядоченные контейнеры

Tags: структуры-данных

Что такое ассоциативные неупорядоченные и упорядоченные контейнеры?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вкратце...
В общем виде - контейнеры, способные хранить пары "ключ/значение" и обеспечивать эффективный поиск значения по ключу (достаточно произвольного типа).

Упорядоченность-неупорядоченность - это, грубо говоря, как хранятся данные, можно ли их все вывести из контейнера упорядоченно по ключу или нет.

В С++ упорядоченный ассоциативный контейнер - это `map` (`multimap`), который позволяет вывести все свое содержимое в порядке "возрастания" ключа. Неупорядоченный контейнер - соответственно `unordered_map`, в котором данные хранятся хитрым способом, обеспечивающим быстрый поиск, но не позволяющим сказать по элементу, например, какой будет следующим...

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*